# git - credential.helper not working when run in a script

Tags: git

I'm using this method for hiding credentials (which were previously on the URL)...

`git -c credential.helper='!f() { echo username=$username; echo password=$password; }; f' submodule add "https://<some git repo>/common.git"`

I have a bash script which calls the above but if fails, outputs...

```
Cloning into '/tmp.DO3a86jfoM/delete-me/common'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://<some git repo>/common.git/
```

However when I CD to the same place and run this command it works.
I've tried outputting the credentials/pwd/whoami to make sure everything is correct. All looks fine. The credentials are definitely ok since they are used further up the script with other commands. The script exits straight after this failed command.

Any ideas what else to check?

EDIT:

Could it be something to do with the password having an exclamation mark (!) in?

Comment: A `!` in the password seems unlikely to be a problem. You're short-cutting normal credential helper rules (you're supposed to examine the argument for `get`, `store`, or `erase` requests) but that shouldn't matter here. The use of lowercase `$password` etc for what must be environment variables is weird stylistically, but should also be OK practically speaking, so it's not clear what's wrong.

Comment: the `$password` is a script argument, as opposed to an environment variable. I inherited this and haven't gone through and corrected everything to be 'best practice'. However, what I have got working is `!f() { echo username=$username; echo \"password=$( echo $password )\"; }; f`. I'm no bash expert but this just looks wrong!

Comment: The "script argument" part seems like odd phrasing: is something doing some sort of preprocessing? In shell scripts, arguments would be `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: It's using getOpts and assigning the arg to `password`.

Comment: So `$password` is a shell variable? If so, how is `$password` getting passed to the shell that runs the `f()` function? That's a *different* shell from the shell that's interpreting some other series of commands, and `$password` is a literal text string passed to the shell that interprets and runs the Git credential helper. ... Aha, that explains why your replacement works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66422044/git-credential-helper-not-working-when-run-in-a-script?noredirect=1#comment117454527_66422044) two [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66422044/git-credential-helper-not-working-when-run-in-a-script?noredirect=1#comment117517070_66422044), I infer that the missing piece of information in your original question goes something like this:

> Here is my script:
>
> ```
> #! /bin/sh
> ... getOpts bits including assignments such as:
>    username=$2; shift 2;;
> ... and
>    password=$2; shift 2;;
> ... or similar with username=$OPTARG, all depending on the getopts flavors
> # setup all done, now for some logging:
> echo "going to run some Git commands now with:"
> echo " user=$username"
> echo " password=$password"
>
> git -c credential.helper='!f() { echo username=$username; echo password=$password; }; f' submodule add "https://<some git repo>/common.git
> ```

The reason this does not work is simple: the single quotes here prevent expansion of shell variables.  So this creates a `credential.helper` that is a shell function `f` whose code is:

```sh
echo username=$username
echo password=$password
```

That is, this shell function has a literal `$username` string in it, and a literal `$password` string in it.  This shell function is then run by a *different shell* than the one that is interpreting the original script.

Because this is a *different* shell, it *does not have a variable named `username` and does not have a variable named `password`*.  The default action on expanding an unset variable is to put in no text.  The result is that the output from function `f` is:

```
username=
password=
```

What we *want* function `f` to do is echo the actual user name, then echo the actual password.

We *could* write the following.  Note that I have split the long lines for display purposes—they need to be joined up again, or you need to use whatever syntax is required to escape the newlines (either method is fine).

```sh
git -c "credential.helper=!f() {
    echo username='$username';
    echo password='$password'; }; f"
    submodule add "https://<some git repo>/common.git"
```

This feeds, to the subshell, the result of expanding the double quoted string.  Since double quotes quote single quotes, but do not prevent variable expansion, `$username` and `$password` will be expanded in place.  So, if in this outer shell, `username` is set to `hello` and `password` is set to `world`, the `-c` option sees the literal string:

```
credential.helper=!f() { echo username='hello'; echo password='world'; }; f
```

(not broken up at spaces since double quotes prevent word splitting) as its (single) argument.  Note that the outer double quotes are completely gone; the inner single quotes around `hello` and `world` (the user name and password) are from the text literal, while the expanded user name and password are supplied by the (outer) shell, as the `-c` argument.

This has some flaws, all of which might be minor enough not to worry about for your particular setup.  The two big obvious ones that I see are these:<sup>1</sup>

- A user name or password that contains any *single quotes* will mess with our quoting.
- The entire `-c` argument is clearly visible in `ps` output, on a Unix-like system.  Other systems with process viewers probably also have ways to examine arguments and/or environment variables passed to programs too.

Using environment variables to smuggle values through to the sub-shell is a legitimate way to fix the first point, and also to fix half of the second point, but if environment variables are visible, there's still a security issue here.

Yet another way to fix this is to smuggle the variable values through to the shell function by having the shell function read them from a pipe or file, pushing the security issue to pipe and/or file security instead.  Of course, if we are going do that, we might as well have a real credential helper, that stores real data in, e.g., encrypted and/or read-protected files.  In other words, instead of fobbing off our security issues to OS files, we could fob them off to OS-provided or third-party *programs*.

A good candidate for the latter is to use ssh.  The secure shell (ssh) system already takes care of all of this stuff, and has a lot more thought and programming-effort behind it than we could possibly come up with in a StackOverflow answer.  Of course it means using `ssh://` URLs instead of `https://` URLs.  But that's really the way to go.  Until then, you can use these somewhat-defective methods, as long as the defects are not a problem for your particular use case.

---

<sup>1</sup>There might always be more, which is the thing about bugs.  About the best we can do is prove some code mathematically, and then hope that (a) our proof is correct and (b) the assumptions we made in the proof, such as that the computer obeys the instructions given and does not have cosmic rays flipping bits in memory and so on, all hold.

Note that there's a third obvious flaw not related to the first two: a Git credential helper is *supposed to* obey its (single) parameter word.  The word `get` means that the helper should print the user name and/or password (and/or other attributes); the word `store` means it should store credentials; and the word `erase` means it should remove (erase) credentials.  For more, see [the gitcredentials documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).  However, at least as of today, each credential helper is only going to be run with these three words, and when it's run with the word `store` or `erase`, its output is ignored.  So, by just blindly printing `username=whatever` and `password=whatever`, we get a helper that suffices for filling in a user name and password during an https authentication attempt—and since this is a `-c` option, it's only being used for this one `git` run.